# How to use `to_sql` in AREL when using `average()`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to the get SQL from AREL, but it does not work in case I use `average(:stars)` :

This works:

```
Review.where("reviewed_user_id = ?", self.reviewed_user_id).to_sql
#=> "SELECT `reviews`.* FROM `reviews` WHERE (reviewed_user_id = 3)"
```

This causes `NoMethodError`:

```
Review.where("reviewed_user_id = ?", self.reviewed_user_id).average(:stars).to_sql
#=> undefined method `to_sql' for 3:Fixnum
```

So that means that `to_sql` is getting called on the result of the AREL instead of on the AREL object - but why?

How to get the generated SQL ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the average method is on `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not Arel, which forces the computation.

```
m = Review.where('id = ?', 42).method(:average)
#=> #<Method: ActiveRecord::Relation(ActiveRecord::Calculations)#average>
m.source_location  # or m.__file__ if you're on a different version of Ruby
#=> ["/Users/jtran/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb", 65]
```

By checking out the internals of `ActiveRecord::Calculations`, you can derive how to get at the SQL that it uses.

```
my_reviewed_user_id = 42
relation = Review.where('reviewed_user_id = ?', my_reviewed_user_id)
column = Arel::Attribute.new(Review.unscoped.table, :stars)
relation.select_values = [column.average]
relation.to_sql
#=> "SELECT AVG(\"reviews\".\"stars\") AS avg_id FROM \"reviews\" WHERE (reviewed_user_id = 42)"
```

Careful if you're working at the console.  `ActiveRecord::Relation` caches things so if you type the above into the console line by line, it will actually not work, because pretty-printing forces the relation.  Separating the above by semicolons and no new lines, however, will work.

Alternatively, you can use Arel directly, like so:

```
my_reviewed_user_id = 42
reviews = Arel::Table.new(:reviews)
reviews.where(reviews[:reviewed_user_id].eq(my_reviewed_user_id)).project(reviews[:stars].average).to_sql
#=> "SELECT AVG(\"reviews\".\"stars\") AS avg_id FROM \"reviews\" WHERE \"users\".\"reviewed_user_id\" = 42"
```

Comment: Super! Thanks for sharing the method you used to figure this out.. will come in handy in future!

Comment: This is why I love Ruby. You can always ask the REPL and source. It's the source in more than one sense of the word!

Comment: This helps me a lot in many different logics. great work man.