# How to get the SQL command via "to_sql" when calculation methods like "count" / "maximum" are used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

```
Message.where("publisher_id==1").to_sql
```

returns:

```
"SELECT     `messages`.* FROM       `messages`  WHERE     (publisher_id==1)"
```

But:

```
Message.maximum(:created_at).to_sql
```

issues an error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

while

```
Message.maximum(:created_at)
```

returns:

```
2011-05-28 15:00:01 UTC
```

Any ideas why the error is issued, and how to get the SQL command when calculation commands (like `count`/`maximum`) are used ?

Comment: The problem here is that Message.maximum(:created_at).class => Time and not ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: See interesting question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173015/how-to-use-to-sql-in-arel-when-using-average