# How do I use functions like CONCAT(), etc. in ARel?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, arel

Is there a way to have `ARel` write (sanitized, possibly aliased, etc.) column names into `CONCAT()` and other SQL functions?

Here's [how to do it with AVG()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173015/how-to-use-to-sql-in-arel-when-using-average)...

```
?> name = Arel::Attribute.new(Arel::Table.new(:countries), :name)
=> #<struct Arel::Attributes::Attribute [...]
?> population = Arel::Attribute.new(Arel::Table.new(:countries), :population)
=> #<struct Arel::Attributes::Attribute [...]
?> Country.select([name, population.average]).to_sql
=> "SELECT `countries`.`name`, AVG(`countries`.`population`) AS avg_id FROM `countries`"
```

(yes, I know that `avg_id` would be the same in every row, just trying to illustrate my question)

So what if I wanted a different function?

```
?> Country.select(xyz).to_sql # Arel::Concat.new(name, population) or something?
=> "SELECT CONCAT(`countries`.`name`, ' ', `countries`.`population`) AS concat_id FROM `countries`"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sequel has a way of selecting columns as `"...".lit` meaning "literal SQL" instead of being interpreted as a string for situations like this. That disables SQL escaping so you can inject whatever you want. Not sure what the AREL equivalent is, but maybe that's an idea.

Comment: I have written a bit more detail on this myself here <http://mrpunkin.com/post/18919379925/using-arel-for-sql-functions>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `NamedFunction`:

```
name = Arel::Attribute.new(Arel::Table.new(:countries), :name)
func = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new 'zomg', [name]
Country.select([name, func]).to_sql
```

Comment: It looks like NamedFunction need to be attached to an attribute? e.g. if I want to group things by dates, could I do `.group(arel_table[:created_at].date)`, without attaching the "date" function directly on "created_at" so I can reuse it elsewhere? (sql: `GROUP BY DATE(created_at)`)

Comment: @AaronPatterson Using your code, `func.to_sql` gives `zomg('countries', 'name')`. I think, the code should be `...Function.new 'zomg', [name]` (with square brackets).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Arel Extensions](https://github.com/Faveod/arel-extensions) gem to have simpler access to functions.

```
> User.where((User[:login] + User[:first_name]).length.in 2..10).to_sql
"SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
 WHERE LENGTH(CONCAT(CAST(`users`.`login` AS char),
                     CAST(`users`.`first_name` AS char)))
         BETWEEN (2) AND (10)"
```