# Using `CONCAT` w/ Arel in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I have a `User` model that has `first_name` and `last_name` attributes. Using Arel I would like to perform a full name search using `CONCAT`. I've read the post at [How do I use functions like CONCAT(), etc. in ARel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304724/how-do-i-use-functions-like-concat-etc-in-arel) which gives me indication that this is possible but I can't quite get the syntax right. So far I have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(query)
    concat = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new 'concat', [arel_table[:first_name], arel_table[:last_name]]
    where ...?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With the latest Arel it's required to use `Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' ')` instead of just String (' '). So the answer nowadays is:

```
SEPARATOR = Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' ')

Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
  'concat',
  [arel_table[:first_name], SEPARATOR, arel_table[:last_name]]
)
```

Comment: `Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' ')` is defined in Arel >= 6, it didn't work for me (Rails 4.0). Simply replace it with `' '` in that case.

Answer (score 8):

If you want an equal search

```
 where(concat.eq("john smith"))

 SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE CONCAT("users"."first_name", "users"."last_name") = 'john smith'
```

If you want a like search

```
where(concat.matches("%john smith%"))

 SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (CONCAT("users"."first_name", "users"."last_name")) ILIKE '%admin%'
```

There are other methods given in the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/Nodes/NamedFunction) that you can use

You might want a space in your concat

```
concat = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
 'concat',
  [arel_table[:first_name], 
  ' ', 
  arel_table[:last_name]]
)
```

Comment: Is there a DB agnostic way to achieve this? Right now I have to check what's my DB adapter (stinks) for this to work in both SQLite: "first_name || ' ' || last_name" and Postgres : SQLite: "CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)"

Comment: A concat node [was added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431714/using-concat-w-arel-in-rails-4) to Arel at the end of 2015.

Comment: You may have error such like ` *** RuntimeError Exception: unsupported: String` afterwards you run the second example, and to fix this use Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' ') instead.