# Rails order by count through two model instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this bit of code where each project can be voted on.  In my views I want to list each project by the order of votes from highest to lowest.

I found one way, but is there a better way to do this?

My way:

**Controller**

```
class Admin::ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @projects = Project.all.sort_by { |project| project.votes.count }
  end
end
```

**Views**

```
- @projects.each do |project|
  %li= project.name
  %li= project.teacher_firstname
  %li= project.teacher_lastname
  %li= project.votes.count
```

I was trying to do something along the lines of `Project.votes.all.order(:desc)` but obviously that doesn't work, but that's what I want to try to do.

And then someone pointed me to [:counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) but that seems a little too much just to count.  No need to add a count column.

Any other suggestions?

**Update**
Okay so two things

1. @jgautsch's worked, but I'm curious, it's a class method wouldn't I
   want to make this an instance method? Or would it not matter?  Just
   take off self? I sometimes get confused (as much as read articles on
   this) of when it's appropriate for instance verses class method.
2. Also, I noticed that I only get projects that have been voted on.
   How would I continue to display them even if there are 0 votes?  I even took out the `limit` and the `num` argument

Comment: Join the `project` table with `vote` group by `project` and count!

Comment: @YanFoto codewise, what does this look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this question: [Rails 3 ActiveRecord: Order by count on association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696005/rails-3-activerecord-order-by-count-on-association)

As described in the linked question, you can either use counter_cache and keep your query to one table (nothing wrong with adding a column here), or do something like this (untested):

```
class Project
  has_many :votes

  def self.top_voted(num = 10)
    select("projects.id, OTHER_ATTRS_YOU_NEED, count(votes.id) AS votes_count")
    .joins(:votes)
    .group("projects.id")
    .order("votes_count DESC")
    .limit(num)
  end
end

Project.top_voted(5) # top 5 most voted projects
```

Comment: actually so if I do this is this is class method and not an instance method.  I guess it wouldn't really matter but I'd have to change up the way I display them in the views, right?

Comment: I'd take out the period after the group statement.  Also, I noticed that I only get projects that have been voted on.  How would I continue to display them even if there are 0 votes?  I took out the limit statement and no dice.

Comment: `.limit` here just limits the number of results. It's typically the best idea to try and pull all records from db, so you might consider using a pagination gem instead of limit.

To include `Projects` with 0 votes, just remove the `.joins(:votes)` line

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. You can do this:

```
Project.select('*, (SELECT count(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.project_id=project.id) as vote_count').order("vote_count DESC")
```

Ugly, I know, but at least its just 1 query.

Would be cool if there's a fully ORM way to do that, something like:

```
Project
  .select(vote_count: Vote.where("project_id = project.id").count)
  .order(vote_count: :desc)
```

**UPDATE:**
another functional way:

```
Project
  .select(
    Vote
      .select('count(*)')
      .where('project_id=projects.id')
      .to_sql.sub(/(.*)/, '*, (\1)as vote_count'))
  .order("vote_count DESC")
```

or maybe we can achieve a more ORMed by using [Arel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173015/how-to-use-to-sql-in-arel-when-using-average) directly or search by Vote (and join with Project inside) instead of search by Project (and join with Vote inside).

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm not sure where you're going with this one, because you're selecting from votes?  I tried it and I get `missing FROM-clause entry for table "project"
LINE 1: ...SELECT count(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.project_id=project.id...`  I mean semantically but it doesn't pull through the views.  I just did `@projects = Project.select('(SELECT count(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.project_id=project.id)`  as vote_count').order("vote_count")  in the controller and used the same views from above.

Comment: was a typo: I wrote `project_id=project.id` but the correct is project**s**, with a "s": `project_id=projects.id`

Comment: sorry, was another error. The 2 queries was missing a '*' to be selected. Also, you want to order in a inverse way. I update the 2, and they should work.

Comment: Oh great, that works!  Now I have to figure out why @jgautsch's query doesn't return all the projects even if they have 0 votes.

Comment: Try to change `joins(:votes)` to `joins("left outer join votes on (project_id=projects.id)")`

Comment: Okay that works. What I've learned through all of this is  I don't like ActiveRecords Query Language...I'm not sure how the arguments are passed in things like `.join` or `select` or `.group`.  I'm much better off used `.find_by_sql`.  Second, I used his exact query but I just stuck this in   `.having("votes_count > -1)`

Comment: I guess overall lesson, rails won't let you someone query through objects in an object oriented way.  You just basically have to use SQL, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69583/discussion-between-gary1410-and-daniel-loureiro).